# why $EX=EY=\frac{2}{3}$ obvious? ${}$ why $DX=DY=2\times \frac{1}{3}\times\frac{2}{3}=\frac{4}{9}$ obvious?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Random trial $E$ has three pairs of incompatible results $A_{1}$,$A_{2}$,and $A_{3}$, and the probability of the three results is $\frac{1}{3}$. If test $E$ is repeated twice independently,$X$ represents the number of times of the result $A_{1}$ in the two trials, and $Y$ represents the number of times of the result $A_{2}$ in the two trials, then the correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Y$ is？

My problem is a basic question.

why $EX=EY=\frac{2}{3}$ obvious?

why $DX=DY=2\times \frac{1}{3}\times\frac{2}{3}=\frac{4}{9}$ obvious?

I am very grateful for any tips and help.

Comment: What does $DX$ mean?

Comment: Said in the textbook : $DX$=E{[X-E(X)]^{2}}

Comment: Oh, so $DX$ is the variance of $X$. Often that's denoted $\text{Var}(X)$.

Comment: @littleO Oh,I know, this is what you mean, next time I will write $Var(x)$

Comment: @littleO Oh, so I don't know how to calculate $DX$ is the variance of $X$. $\text{Var}(X)$.

Comment: @littleO The D may stand for dispersion, an old name for variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $p = 1/3$ and $N = 2$. We know that the expected value of a binomial random variable is 
$$
E(X) = Np = 2 \cdot \frac13.
$$

There is also a standard formula for the variance of a binomial random variable.

Comment: Thank you, you are very good.

Comment: Ok, I know now, thank you very much, my foundation is not good, thank you for your patience.

Comment: why $X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $N = 2$?

Comment: @exgirlfriend The "story" of a binomial random variable $X$ is that you perform $N$ independent trials, each of which is either a success (with probability $p$) or a failure, and $X$ tells you the number of successes that occur. A classic example is flipping a biased coin $N$ times. In the problem you posted, if we consider event $A_1$ to be a "success", then our random variable $X$ tells us the number of "successes" in two independent trials. So $X$ is a binomial random variable.

Comment: wow thank you  You are such a good person